# Start javascript from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, master-pages

Hi I have a usercontrol which includes some JavaScript, if I add the control to a standard web page I can start the JavaScript in the body tag, like this

```
<body onLoad="Start()">
```

The problem is that I need to add the control to a webpage which is inside a masterpage, how do I then start the script when a page inside a masterpage doesn't have a body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the body tag to runat server and give it an id.

```
<body id="masterBody" runat="server">
```

Then on page load:

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("masterBody");
body.Attributes.Add("onload", "Start()");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register it using:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()
```

For your case, it would be this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyScript", "Start()", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Include jQuery and put your initialization code inside `$(document).ready()`.

If you want to strictly use .NET functionality, and your page is properly marked up with `runat="server"`, you could use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to the DOM `document.ready` event to load your content after the document has completed rendering